# SQL with 0 counts

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following sql query :

```
SELECT DATE(procedures.start) date, name, COUNT(procedure_types.id) count
FROM `procedure_types`
  LEFT OUTER JOIN procedures on procedure_types.id = procedures.procedure_type_id
WHERE (DATE(procedures.start) = '2009-10-24')
GROUP BY DATE(procedures.start), procedure_types.id
ORDER BY DATE(procedures.start), procedure_types.id
```

There are two tables procedures & procedure_types.
Procedure has procedure_type_id which points to the procedure_types table.

The query is executing fine, but I want to list the procedure_types with count(0) even if they aren't being referenced by any procedures on that date.

I know it's something to do with the joins..can someone please help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your WHERE clause is excluding procedure_types with no procedures.  You need to move it to the JOIN:

```
SELECT DATE(procedures.start) date, name, COUNT(procedure_types.id) count
FROM `procedure_types`
LEFT OUTER JOIN procedures on procedure_types.id = procedures.procedure_type_id
    AND DATE(procedures.start) = '2009-10-24'
GROUP BY DATE(procedures.start), procedure_types.id
ORDER BY DATE(procedures.start), procedure_types.id
```

Comment: Thanks that solved it! Thanks a lot Greg, and now that you have mentioned it, it seems to make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

`Left Outer Join` will select all records from `Procedures` table and only matching from `Procedure_Types`. You want to select all records from `Procedure_Types` even if no matching record in `Procedures`, so you need **`Right Outer Join`**. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) for more info on JOINS.

Comment: Hey, this wasn't helping me, don't know why.